# limit of $\int_{-\frac{n}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n^2}\right)dx$ and its summation analog.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, infinity

I'm getting confused about taking the following limits I would be appreciated if somebody could guide me through

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{-\frac{n}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n^2}\right)dx
\end{equation}

and also the discrete version:

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{x=-\frac{n}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n^2}\right)
\end{equation}

Can anybody help me with this?

**Edited**: I am more looking for an asymptotic behavior so if the answer is $\infty$ an asymptotic behavior would also suffice

Comment: Are you sure that a $\frac 1 n$ is not missing for the integral ?

Comment: *Hint.* In both cases, note that $$\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n^2}\right)\geq\exp\left(-\frac{(3n/2)^2}{2n^2}\right)=e^{-9/8}$$ holds for any $x \in [-n/2, n/2]$. For the asymptotic behavior, note that $$\frac{1}{n}\int_{-\frac{n}{2}}^{\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-n)^2}{2n^2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\stackrel{(x=nu)}{=}\int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^{\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(u-1)^2}{2}\right)\,\mathrm{d}u$$ and similarly for the summation.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes I am sure, see the question again I made an edit

Comment: @SangchulLee please could you be more clear?, I mean I don't get exactly how does that help

Comment: @Jason, The lower bound allows to prove that both the integral and the sum diverges at least as fast as $e^{-9/8}n$. I also briefly addressed how to identify their asymptotic behavior as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Thank you so much, please correct me if I'm wrong, so we don't need the $\frac{1}{n}$ factor for identifying the asymptotic behavior of the summation right?

Comment: @Jason, Indeed it is not necessary. I just introduced that factor to create a quantity that converges to a non-zero finite value.

Comment: @SangchulLee I'm sorry I think I didn't ask my question in the comment clearly, so I ask it in another but better way. if I want the second summation to converge to what factor should I multiply it?

Comment: You would need the same factor $1/n$. The the resulting sum will be a Riemann sum that converges to an integral with a non-zero value.

Comment: @SangchulLee yes thank you sorry if im asking too much but would your explanation still be valid if the summand was $exp(\frac{x^2}{2n^2})$ instead what it is right now?

Comment: No worries. Indeed, the argument continues to hold as long as you replace the summand by $f(\frac{x}{n})$. The original sum corresponds to $f(x)=\exp\left(-\frac{(x-1)^2}{2}\right)$, whereas your new summand would correspond to $f(x)=\exp\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)$.

Answer (score 1):

For the integral, the change of variables $u=\frac{x-n}{n}$ gives
$$
n\int^{-\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{3}{2}}e^{-\frac{u^2}{2}}\,du=n\int^{\frac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\frac{(u-1)^2}{2}}\,du
$$
So the first limit is $\infty$.

The limit in the discrete version is also $\infty$ since
$$
\sum^{\tfrac{n}{2}}_{k=-\tfrac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{k}{n}-1\big)^2}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}\int^{\tfrac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}\,du
$$

If $I_n$ denotes the first sequence in your problem and $D_n$ its discrete version, what escapes me is how $I_n$ and $D_n$ differ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (asymptotics), that is

- how does
  $\Delta_n:=I_n-D_n$ behave? for instance, is $I_n-D_n=O(n^{-\alpha})$ for some $\alpha>0$?
- Clearly $\lim_n \frac{I_n}{D_n}=1$, but how fast? for instance, is $\frac{I_n}{D_n}-1 =o(n^{-\beta})$ for some $\beta>0$

$\Delta_n$ is the error in approximating an integral by Riemman sums, i.e.
\begin{aligned}
\Delta_n&=\sum^{\tfrac{n}{2}}_{k=-\tfrac{n}{2}}\frac{1}{n} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{k}{n}-1\big)^2}-\int^{\tfrac{1}{2}}_{-\frac{1}{2}}e^{-\tfrac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}\,du\\
&=\sum^{\tfrac{n}{2}}_{k=-\tfrac{n}{2}}\int^{\tfrac{k+1}{n}}_{\tfrac{k}{n}}\Big(e^{-\frac{1}{2}\big(\tfrac{k}{n}-1\big)^2}-e^{-\frac{1}{2}(u-1)^2}\Big)\,du
\end{aligned}

To answer the firs question about asymptotics, one may try to use the mean value theorem to see if we can get bounds from below and above. But still some work to do.

Comment: I'm confused why do we face an error term? I mean when you divide the summand by n isn't it became a Riemann sum? if so then why we have an error approximation?

Comment: If your concern is only about the  limits your defined in your question, then if corse both diverge to infinity. I understood that you were also interested in the asymptotics as in $b_n=a_n+O(n^\alpha)$ or something like that. So far we only have $a_n\sim b_n$ (i.e. $\lim_n\frac{a_n}{b_n}=1$. In any case, if you have what you need, no need to get further terms or estimates on the difference between $a_n$ and $b_n$ or how fast $a_n/b_nn$ converges to $1$.

Comment: I edited my answer a little to make this point, hopefully, much clearer.

Comment: Like I said, your sum diverges to $infty$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$, That is because your sum ($D_n$ in my notation) is can be express as $D_n=nR_n$, where $R_n$ is a Riemann approximation to the intgegral. So $R_n$ converges to a positive number and so $D_n$ diverges. The asymptotics are more delicate. I laid down some idea for you in my answer.