# calculating $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=-\frac{nf}{2}}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha)i^2}$

Tags: limits, summation, riemann-sum, gaussian

I am interested in calculating the following limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=-\frac{nf}{2}}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha)i^2}
\end{equation}

where $f$ and $\alpha$ are positive real-valued constants. does anybody have any idea how to proceed? any idea or approximation or even an asymptotic behavior would be welcomed.

i tried using Riemann sum formula for it but i failed since for the Riemann sum assuming $\Delta=\frac{b-a}{n}$the summand should have the form $f(\frac{m}{n})$ but as we see it doesn't have that form. for that reason i couldn't go any further using Riemann sum.

Comment: As you enter in topic try to write it as a Riemann sum and write the corresponding integral then we will see how to cope with it.

Comment: i tried but the point is the summation does not have the form$f(\frac{m}{n})$ so I failed trying to write a Riemann sum for it

Comment: Actually you have $(i/n) ^2$ and $(i^2)$ terms.  write product of two sum. One will be Riemman, the second one can be compared to Gaussian integral

Comment: @EDX Im sorry im confused how can you write this summation as a product of those two sum you have mentioned? can you explain more?

Comment: The answer is zero. The sum, as written, is finite.

Comment: @Andrei how did you come up with zero? could you explain more?

Comment: The sum isnt finite, because $n$ goes to the infinity so summation bound varies.

Comment: The sum isnt finite, because $n$ goes to the infinity so summation bound varies.

Comment: @EDX can you show it mathematically i mean usually it sounds like something is infinite but when you write it it became finite

Comment: Mathematically the bounds depends on $n$ which goes to infinity hence it is an infinite sum

Comment: @EDX if a sum has an infinite number of terms it does not means that it's not finite. For example $$\sum_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$$

Comment: Yes obviously! I didn't understand you was meaning finite valued which was for me absurd to say the sum is finite in terms of number of terms

Comment: Seems that you don't have quite a Riemann sum but your sequence can be majorize it by the a Riemann sum approximating $2\int^{f/2}_0e^{-t^2}$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz actually i need something more than that much roughly approximation maybe a better approximation i would be appreciated if you have any idea that helps to get closer to the real answer or having better approximation

Comment: QC_QAOA just provided an answer that looks reasonable to me. The sum you presented here is different from the one you posted here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3721999/limit-of-int-fracn2-fracn2-exp-left-fracx-n22n2-right/3722826#3722826

Comment: I did not ask that though but yea QC_QAOA provided a nice answer

Answer (score 1):

Let's just look at large enough $n$, such that $\frac 1n \ll\alpha$. Then the sum becomes (in the limit $n\to\infty$)
$$S=\sum_{i=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha i^2}$$
But this sum is just a little larger than the integral $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$$
In fact the only thing that I care is that the sum is finite. When you divide by a large $n$, you get $0$.

Answer (score 1):

We have

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=-\frac{nf}{2}}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i^2}=\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i^2}-\frac{1}{n}$$

This can be compared to a geometric series

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i^2}\leq \sum_{i=0}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i}=\frac{e^{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)}-e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)\frac{nf}{2}}}{e^{\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)}-1}<\frac{e^{\left(1+\alpha\right)}}{e^\alpha-1}$$

Then

$$0\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=-\frac{nf}{2}}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i^2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{2}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{\frac{nf}{2}}e^{-\left(\frac{1}{n^2}+\alpha\right)i^2}-\frac{1}{n}\right]$$
$$\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\left[\frac{2}{n}\frac{e^{\left(1+\alpha\right)}}{e^\alpha-1}-\frac{1}{n}\right]=0-0=0$$

Thus, the sequence converges to zero.

Comment: Thank you , is there a way to find an asymptotic expression of the sum? like how fast it converge to 0 or anything like that?

Comment: It decays at least as $O(\frac1n)$. In fact, this seems to be optimal by Andrei's argument.